# Can one fix Tzitzis during the Omer?

Tags: tzitzis, sefirat-ha-omer, invalid-pasul

Is it permissible to fix Tzitzis during the Omer, or would doing so make them "new garments"? Would one be allowed to fix them, then wait until *after* the Omer to wear them?

Comment: As a reminder, don't rely on this site for practicalities: address practical questions to your own rabbi.

Comment: New garments are not prohibited during the omer period per the actual halacha

Comment: @msh210 Why? Is no one on this knowledgeable enough to anwser such a question? No one can open a sefer and see it for themselves? Or does one have to be an "ordained" Rabbi to be able to text the questioner on WhatsApp?

Comment: @Moshe, I'm glad you asked. [Here's why.](/q/9146/170)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no prohibition - recorded in classical Jewish halachic works - forbidding buying and wearing new clothes during the Sefira.

That is a prohibition mentioned in the laws of the 9 days and mourning.

So, yes, you can fix them and wear them during the Sefira.

Check [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 120](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.120?lang=bi) or [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 493](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.493.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and Aruch HaShulchan [ibid](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.493?lang=bi) and the Shuchan Aruch haRav that all both deal with the laws of the Sefira and only mention haircut, marriages and making merry (dancing, music, etc.)  and women not doing any work from nightfall until they have counted.

KSA:

> בִּימֵי הַסְּפִירָה מֵתוּ תַּלְמִידֵי רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא בְּל"ג יוֹם, וְלָכֵן נוֹהֲגִין בְּיָמִים אֵלּוּ קְצָת אֲבֵלוּת, שֶׁאֵין נוֹשְׂאִין נָשִׁים וְאֵין מִסְתַּפְּרִים.‏

SA:

> דינים הנוהגים בימי העומר. ובו ד' סעיפים:‏
>
> נוהגים שלא לישא אשה בין פסח לעצרת עד ל"ג בעומר מפני שבאותו זמן מתו תלמידי ר' עקיבא אבל לארס ולקדש שפיר דמי ונשואין נמי מי שקפץ וכנס אין עונשין אותו: הגה מיהו מל"ג בעומר ואילך הכל שרי (אבודרהם וב"י ומנהגים):‏
>   ב: נוהגים שלא להסתפר עד ל"ג לעומר